# How can I get a query of possible login names for SQL job owner?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-job

I'm trying to get the list of all possible login names for a job owner. The following query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins
WHERE hasaccess=1
```

gives me close to what I'm looking for but it returns additional login names that I do not find in the Browse Objects dialog box using SSMS (such as `##MS_AgentSigningCertificate##` or `BUILTIN\Administrators`). I cannot find any logic in sys.syslogins table to discriminate those records. I looked in other logins tables but nothing comes closer than sys.syslogins.

SQL Server is version 10.50 (2008R2) but I'm looking for a query that will give me the results for this version or earlier.

What am I missing?

Comment: FYI, you should really stop using those old compatibility views like `syslogins`; they are designed for old SQL Server 2000 databases. Switch to the new `sys` objects. [sys.syslogins (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslogins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

@Larnu pointed me in the right direction.

Query that solves my question is:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE [type] IN ('S', 'U')
```